# Need to open a script in next tab and should be work in all browser

Tags: javascript

`win` giving me `NULL` value. I want open script in new tab but here `window.open` not working. Here I have use `window.open` method. But when I try to console it, it giving me `null` value.

```
        $scope.viewScript = function (url) {
            console.log(url);
            $http.post(server_url + '/carrier_script', {
                access_token: access_token,
                carrier_id: url,
            }).success(function(data)
        {
            console.log("data",data.data[0].script_file)
            var script_url=data.data[0].script_file;
            console.log("script_url",script_url);
            setTimeout(function(){
                console.log(script_url)
               var win=  window.open(script_url, "_blank");
                // console.log(win);
                // win.focus();
                console.log(win)
            },2000)


        })
        // var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        // win.focus();
```

Comment: *Open a script* as in run script in new tab or just display the code, i.e. serve as static file content?

Comment: actually script is just a pdf . just want to display the content of script

Comment: Is using js mandatory? I think you can use `a` tag in html with `target="_blank"` to achieve it. Or maybe `createElement` in js and then click it programatically.

Comment: By default popups get blocked if they were not connected directly to a user interaction (usually click). You are making an asynchronous request here, and try to open the popup in the success callback - that is _not_ directly connected to a user interaction, as far as the browser is concerned. I am assuming that `$scope.viewScript` gets called on click on something? Then you could open the popup window first (using `about:blank` as URL), so that it is directly connected to user interaction, make your AJAX request, and then change the location of the popup afterwards in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no problem with your code, but in the modern web browsers the users can turn on/off popup windows. So you might enable the popups first and then your code will work.